# How to make a custom chest in Minecraft 1.12.2 modding?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I made a custom chest in my mod, but there are few problems. The item texture doesn't work, the chest is always facing south and it doesn't show item labels  when I hover over items in it. How to solve these problems? Thanks for help!

Here is the code:
MoneyChest

```
package com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced;

import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.Main;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.tileentity.TileEntityMoneyChest;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.init.ModBlocks;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.init.ModItems;

import net.minecraft.block.BlockContainer;
import net.minecraft.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.inventory.InventoryHelper;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumBlockRenderType;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumFacing;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.math.AxisAlignedBB;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.IBlockAccess;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class MoneyChest extends BlockContainer {

    public MoneyChest(String name) {
        super(Material.IRON);
        setSoundType(SoundType.STONE);
        setCreativeTab(Main.RM_TAB1);
        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setRegistryName(name);

        ModBlocks.BLOCKS.add(this);
        ModItems.ITEMS.add(new ItemBlock(this).setRegistryName(this.getRegistryName()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBlockActivated(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ) {
        if(!worldIn.isRemote) {
            playerIn.openGui(Main.instance, Main.GUI_MONEY_CHEST, worldIn, pos.getX(), pos.getY(), pos.getZ());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void breakBlock(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state) {
        TileEntityMoneyChest tilemoneychest = (TileEntityMoneyChest) worldIn.getTileEntity(pos);
        InventoryHelper.dropInventoryItems(worldIn, pos, tilemoneychest);
        super.breakBlock(worldIn, pos, state);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockPlacedBy(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityLivingBase placer, ItemStack stack) {
        if(stack.hasDisplayName()) {
            TileEntity tilemoneychest = worldIn.getTileEntity(pos);

            if(tilemoneychest instanceof TileEntityMoneyChest) {
                ((TileEntityMoneyChest)tilemoneychest).setCustomName(stack.getDisplayName());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TileEntity createNewTileEntity(World worldIn, int meta) {
        return new TileEntityMoneyChest();
    }

    @Override
    public EnumBlockRenderType getRenderType(IBlockState state) {
        return EnumBlockRenderType.ENTITYBLOCK_ANIMATED;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullBlock(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    public static final AxisAlignedBB MONEY_CHEST_AABB = new AxisAlignedBB(0.0625D, 0, 0.0625D, 0.9375D, 0.875D, 0.9375D);

    @Override
    public boolean isFullCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpaqueCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public AxisAlignedBB getBoundingBox(IBlockState state, IBlockAccess source, BlockPos pos) {
        return MONEY_CHEST_AABB;
    }

}
```

TileEntityMoneyChest

```
package com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.tileentity;

import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.Main;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.container.ContainerMoneyChest;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.InventoryPlayer;
import net.minecraft.init.SoundEvents;
import net.minecraft.inventory.Container;
import net.minecraft.inventory.ItemStackHelper;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntityLockableLoot;
import net.minecraft.util.ITickable;
import net.minecraft.util.NonNullList;
import net.minecraft.util.SoundCategory;
import net.minecraft.util.math.AxisAlignedBB;

public class TileEntityMoneyChest extends TileEntityLockableLoot implements ITickable {

    private NonNullList<ItemStack> chestContents = NonNullList.<ItemStack>withSize(72, ItemStack.EMPTY);
    public int numPlayersUsing, ticksSinceSync;
    public float lidAngle, prevLidAngle;

    @Override
    public int getSizeInventory() {
        return 72;
    }

    @Override
    public int getInventoryStackLimit() {
        return 50;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        for(ItemStack stack : this.chestContents) {
            if(!stack .isEmpty()) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.hasCustomName() ? this.customName : "container.money_chest";
    }

    @Override
    public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.readFromNBT(compound);
        this.chestContents = NonNullList.<ItemStack>withSize(this.getSizeInventory(), ItemStack.EMPTY);

        if(!checkLootAndRead(compound)) ItemStackHelper.loadAllItems(compound, chestContents);
        if(compound.hasKey("CustomName", 8)) this.customName = compound.getString("CustomName");
    }

    @Override
    public NBTTagCompound writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.writeToNBT(compound);

        if(!this.checkLootAndWrite(compound)) ItemStackHelper.saveAllItems(compound, chestContents);
        if(compound.hasKey("CustomName", 8)) compound.setString("CustomName", this.customName);

        return compound;
    }

    @Override
    public Container createContainer(InventoryPlayer playerInventory, EntityPlayer playerIn) {
        return new ContainerMoneyChest(playerInventory, this, playerIn);
    }

    @Override
    public String getGuiID() {
        return Main.MODID + ":money_chest";
    }

    @Override
    protected NonNullList<ItemStack> getItems() {
        return this.chestContents;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        if (!this.world.isRemote && this.numPlayersUsing != 0 && (this.ticksSinceSync + pos.getX() + pos.getY() + pos.getZ()) % 200 == 0) {
            this.numPlayersUsing = 0;
            float f = 5.0F;

            for (EntityPlayer entityplayer : this.world.getEntitiesWithinAABB(EntityPlayer.class, new AxisAlignedBB((double)((float)pos.getX() - 5.0F), (double)((float)pos.getY() - 5.0F), (double)((float)pos.getZ() - 5.0F), (double)((float)(pos.getX() + 1) + 5.0F), (double)((float)(pos.getY() + 1) + 5.0F), (double)((float)(pos.getZ() + 1) + 5.0F)))) {
                if (entityplayer.openContainer instanceof ContainerMoneyChest) {
                    if (((ContainerMoneyChest)entityplayer.openContainer).getChestInventory() == this) {
                        ++this.numPlayersUsing;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.prevLidAngle = this.lidAngle;
        float f1 = 0.1F;

        if (this.numPlayersUsing > 0 && this.lidAngle == 0.0F) {
            double d1 = (double)pos.getX() + 0.5D;
            double d2 = (double)pos.getZ() + 0.5D;
            this.world.playSound((EntityPlayer)null, d1, (double)pos.getY() + 0.5D, d2, SoundEvents.BLOCK_IRON_TRAPDOOR_OPEN, SoundCategory.BLOCKS, 0.5F, this.world.rand.nextFloat() * 0.1F + 0.9F);
        }

        if (this.numPlayersUsing == 0 && this.lidAngle > 0.0F || this.numPlayersUsing > 0 && this.lidAngle < 1.0F) {
            float f2 = this.lidAngle;

            if (this.numPlayersUsing > 0) {
                this.lidAngle += 0.1F;
            }
            else {
                this.lidAngle -= 0.1F;
            }

            if (this.lidAngle > 1.0F) {
                this.lidAngle = 1.0F;
            }

            float f3 = 0.5F;

            if (this.lidAngle < 0.5F && f2 >= 0.5F) {
                double d3 = (double)pos.getX() + 0.5D;
                double d0 = (double)pos.getZ() + 0.5D;
                this.world.playSound((EntityPlayer)null, d3, (double)pos.getY() + 0.5D, d0, SoundEvents.BLOCK_IRON_TRAPDOOR_CLOSE, SoundCategory.BLOCKS, 0.5F, this.world.rand.nextFloat() * 0.1F + 0.9F);
            }

            if (this.lidAngle < 0.0F) {
                this.lidAngle = 0.0F;
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void openInventory(EntityPlayer player) {
        ++this.numPlayersUsing;
        this.world.addBlockEvent(pos, this.getBlockType(), 1, this.numPlayersUsing);
        this.world.notifyNeighborsOfStateChange(pos, this.getBlockType(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public void closeInventory(EntityPlayer player) {
        --this.numPlayersUsing;
        this.world.addBlockEvent(pos, this.getBlockType(), 1, this.numPlayersUsing);
        this.world.notifyNeighborsOfStateChange(pos, this.getBlockType(), false);
    }
}
```

ContainerMoneyChest

```
package com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.container;

import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.tileentity.TileEntityMoneyChest;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.InventoryPlayer;
import net.minecraft.inventory.Container;
import net.minecraft.inventory.Slot;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

public class ContainerMoneyChest extends Container {

    private final int numRows;
    private final TileEntityMoneyChest chestInventory;

    public ContainerMoneyChest(InventoryPlayer playerInv, TileEntityMoneyChest chestInventory, EntityPlayer player) {

        this.chestInventory = chestInventory;
        this.numRows = 2; //chest rows
        chestInventory.openInventory(player);

        for(int i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(chestInventory, j + i*9, 17 + j*18, 15 + i*18));//17 - XposFromLeft;  tagum15s - YposFromTop
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(playerInv, x + y*9 + 9, 8 + x*18, 72 + y*18)); //72 - YposFromTopTex(Inventory)
            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(playerInv, x, 8 + x*18, 130)); //130 - YposFromTopTex(hotbar)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canInteractWith(EntityPlayer playerIn) {
        return this.chestInventory.isUsableByPlayer(playerIn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onContainerClosed(EntityPlayer playerIn) {
        super.onContainerClosed(playerIn);
        chestInventory.closeInventory(playerIn);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack transferStackInSlot(EntityPlayer playerIn, int index) {
        ItemStack itemstack = ItemStack.EMPTY;
        Slot slot = this.inventorySlots.get(index);

        if (slot != null && slot.getHasStack()) {
            ItemStack itemstack1 = slot.getStack();
            itemstack = itemstack1.copy();

            if (index < this.numRows * 8) {
                if (!this.mergeItemStack(itemstack1, this.numRows * 8, this.inventorySlots.size(), true)) {
                    return ItemStack.EMPTY;
                }
            }
            else if (!this.mergeItemStack(itemstack1, 0, this.numRows * 8, false)) {
                return ItemStack.EMPTY;
            }

            if (itemstack1.isEmpty())  {
                slot.putStack(ItemStack.EMPTY);
            }
            else { slot.onSlotChanged(); }
        }
        return itemstack;
    }

    public TileEntityMoneyChest getChestInventory() {
        return this.chestInventory;
    }

}
```

GuiMoneyChest

```
package com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.gui;

import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.Main;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.container.ContainerMoneyChest;
import com.rinventor.rinventedmod.blocks.advanced.tileentity.TileEntityMoneyChest;

import net.minecraft.client.gui.inventory.GuiContainer;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.InventoryPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class GuiMoneyChest extends GuiContainer {

    private static final ResourceLocation GUI_CHEST = new ResourceLocation(Main.MODID + ":textures/gui/money_chest.png");
    private final InventoryPlayer playerInventory;
    private final TileEntityMoneyChest temc;

    public GuiMoneyChest(InventoryPlayer playerInventory, TileEntityMoneyChest chestInventory, EntityPlayer player) {

        super(new ContainerMoneyChest(playerInventory, chestInventory, player));
        this.playerInventory = playerInventory;
        this.temc = chestInventory;

        this.xSize = 176;
        this.ySize = 154;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawGuiContainerForegroundLayer(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        this.fontRenderer.drawString(this.temc.getDisplayName().getUnformattedText(), 14, 4, 0);//3120942-green
        this.fontRenderer.drawString(this.playerInventory.getDisplayName().getUnformattedText(), 8, this.ySize-93, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawGuiContainerBackgroundLayer(float partialTicks, int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        GlStateManager.color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(GUI_CHEST);
        this.drawTexturedModalRect(this.guiLeft, this.guiTop, 0, 0, this.xSize, this.ySize);
    }
}
```

I also have ModelMoneyChest and RenderMoneyChest files, but these are not the reason for the problems I got.

Comment: All of your problems likely started with `extends BlockContainer`. BlockContainer does *tons* of stuff you don't want or need. Just extend Block and override `hasTileEntity(BlockState)` and `getTileEntity(BlockState)`. Second, Vanilla renders chests through a lot of special-case code, so you'll need to write a renderer for your own chest.

Comment: I would recommend going here: https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/